# key value pair, loop through a dictionary vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to read a column one cell at a time and store it the cell as a key and its frequency as its value. Then I want to place all key-value pairs into a range say column P and Q. I think I got the first part of the job done with the code below (not 100% on it though) Now how can place the key value pairs to a range?

```
Dim D As Dictionary
Set D = New Dictionary
Dim DR As Range


 Set DR = Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(2, 2).End(xlDown))

    For Each Cell In DR.Cells

        If Not D.Exists(Cell.Value) Then
        D.Add Cell, 1
        Else
        D.Exists (Cell.Value)
        D.Item(Cell.Value) = D.Item(Cell.Value) + 1
        End If

    Next Cell
```

I roughly have the idea of looping through the dictionary per each key but I cant do

```
Dim k as key
```

any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try below code :

```
Sub test()

    Dim D As Dictionary
    Set D = New Dictionary
    Dim DR As Range


    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row


    Set DR = Range("A2:A" & lastRow)

    For Each Cell In DR

        If D.Exists(CStr(Cell.Value)) = False Then
               D.Add CStr(Cell.Value), 1
        Else
            D.Exists (Cell.Value)
            D.Item(Cell.Value) = D.Item(Cell.Value) + 1
        End If

    Next

    i = 2
    For Each Key In D
        Range("P" & i).Value = Key
        Range("Q" & i).Value = D(Key)
        i = i + 1
    Next


End Sub
```